# Android prevent App Crashing

Tags: android

When my app crashed in different exceptions my application closed with an error message

> Unforthunately, "AppName" has stoped

I want to prevent this and keeps app alive, If any one knows the best practise, about that situation, please help me.

Thanks

Comment: post stack trace

Comment: show logcat error

Comment: Hi, John you need to post logtrace (logcat) for better solution.

Comment: Hi All, I ask any best practices, how keeps app alive, about that situation,

Comment: please follow my answer please

Comment: Best Practice? Write good codes, do proper testing and attach Crashlytics or Firebase to log crashes and correct them for the next build.

Comment: no, you can't and should not. When the app crashes, it means that there is something wrong with the app. And you have to fix that "something wrong" instead of hiding it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I did. This class redirects the user to my login screen when ever the app crashes unexpectedly.

```
public class DefaultExceptionHandler implements Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {

        Activity activity;

        public DefaultExceptionHandler(Activity activity) {
            this.activity = activity;
        }

        @Override
        public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, final Throwable ex) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(activity, LoginActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(activity.getString(R.string.app_crashed), ex);
            Log.d("ERROR","---------" + ex.getMessage());
            Log.d("ERROR","--------" + ex.getCause());
            Log.d("ERROR","--------" + Arrays.toString(ex.getStackTrace()));
            activity.startActivity(intent);
            activity.finish();

            System.exit(0);
        }

}
```

and call it this way in your onCreate() method:

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new DefaultExceptionHandler(this));
```

Comment: This is really nice, then When an  app crashes in fragment Is this work correctly

Comment: @JOHNMORGAN yes. Call the method from where you initialize your fragment.

Comment: @JOHNMORGAN Please upvote my answer if it helped you.

Comment: https://hfararjeh98.medium.com/never-crash-without-try-catch-c1f1e756295a

Answer (score 1):

You can use try catch code for that.

for example:

```
try{
        // your code here
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

    }
```

your apps not crash ever. Thanks.

Comment: please follow my ans. Best of luck!

Comment: You mean, have try catch in each and every part of the code?

Comment: @MohammedAtif, no, where possible crash , there he use try catch  :)

Comment: So thats exactly what he is asking, How to detect the possibility of app crash and correct that code. I mean if you know your code might crash, you will correct it then and there right?